# select2-rails tags dropdown not working when clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-select2, select2-rails

I have the following field

```rb
<%= f.collection_select :tag_list, @tags.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, { class: 'select2', multiple: true } %>
```

I have added the `select2-rails` gem and have added the js and css in the respected files

`//= require select2-full` application.js
`*= require select2` application.css

I have also added the following to my application.js file

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.select2').select2();
});
```

However, I'm getting the following
[image]
Won't even dropdown.

**Rendered HTML**

```html
<select class="select2 hasCustomSelect" multiple="multiple" name="contact[tag_list][]" id="contact_tag_list" style="appearance: menulist-button; position: absolute; opacity: 0; height: 33px; font-size: 13px; width: 1563px;">
  <option value="28">ANFIM</option>
  <option value="11">BWT filter</option>
  ...
</select>
```

When adding the select2 js in the application.js I also get this
[image]

app.js

```js
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery.min
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require prototype
//= require moment.min
//= require fullcalendar
//= require lib_ext
//= require BigDecimal-all-1.0.1.min
//= require dialog
//= require widgets
//= require classes
//= require payroll
//= require account_context_menu
//= require plan_table
//= require requirements
//= require help
//= require help_data
//= require jquery.contextMenu.js
//= require jquery.treetable
//= require jquery.jstree
//= require select2-full 
//= require plugins
//= require scripts
//= require additional
//= require effects
//= require clusterize.min
//= require consolidated_orders
//= require sales_invoices
//= require main
//= require journals/auto_reversal
//= require budgets/new
//= require budgets/export

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.select2').select2();
});
```

Comment: can you add the rendered HTML code here as well?

Comment: I've added the rendered html not all options though as there's a lot @Mshka

Comment: one last thing as it might be a initializing issue: can you post the content of `application.js`

Comment: Added my application.js @Mshka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running

```js
$(function() {
    $('.select2').select2();
});
```

`$(document).ready` have been removed in jquery3

I could not reproduce the issue, I have the same libraries as you and imported css assets aswell, except that I have `//= require jquery` instead of `//= require jquery.min` but should not be a problem try running `$('.select2').select2();` directly in your js console and see if it works - if so it looks like you have a problem with your jquery ready function

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is null` when running `$('.select2').select2();` in the js console

Comment: can you try `jQuery` and `$` in your console and let me know which one works?

Comment: Both of them work https://i.gyazo.com/f26daeb844ce42010505db48c9803b6c.png

Comment: try running `jQuery('.select2').select2();` on the page your have your form on

Comment: Ah perfect https://i.gyazo.com/349b864d19699c48e0025f2fc796e537.png, I don't deal with jQuery much as it shows haha, thank you.

Comment: Nice! Careful tho, this might be something interfering and affecting your jquery library. $ and JQuery should work the same unless you have a library that state otherwise on purpose, good luck